# Как добавить поле в шаблон Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Во вьюшке добавил 1 строку:

```
$this->title = $devArtView['title'];
$this->descr = $devArtView['descr']; // добавил эту строку, в массиве из БД она есть
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-about">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <p>Это страница</p>
</div>
```

В layouts/main.php добавил `<?= Html::encode($this->descr) ?>` по аналогии с тем как выводится title

```
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta name="description" content="<?= Html::encode($this->descr) ?>">

    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
```

Ошибка:
Setting unknown property: yii\web\View::descr
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У view нет свойства descr, отсюда и ошибка такая.
Вам следует `description` выводит одним из 2-х способов

1. В контроллере:

   \Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
       'name' => 'description',
       'content' => 'Description set inside controller',
   ]);
2. Во view:

   $this->registerMetaTag([
       'name' => 'description',
       'content' => 'Description set inside view',
   ]);